# AngularJS: Hide Sidebar in Login (and Signup) view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need a sidebar in an Angular app. The sidebar should be present in every views but one, the login view (and probably others, like signup).

At the moment, the sidebar its a view, included in index.html:

```html
<div ng-include src="'assets/partials/sidebar.html'"></div>
```

What is the best way to do it?

(I'm using ui-router.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) or [UIRouter](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router).

These will allow you to define view behavior for a given URL in your app.

For example, if you wanted to define routes (using ngRoute) for '/login' and '/dashboard', it might look like this:

```
angular.module('ngRouteExample', ['ngRoute'])

 .controller('MainController', function($scope) {
     // Do stuff...
 })

.controller('DashboardController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
     // Do Stuff...
 })

 .controller('LoginController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
     // Do Stuff...
 })

 .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
   $routeProvider
   .when('/dashboard', {
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
    controller: 'DashboardController',

  })
  .when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
    controller: 'LoginController'
  })
});
```

And in your index.html:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

Then, you can create a separate directive like:

```
<sidebar></sidebar>
```

And include it in dashboard.html but not in login.html

**EDIT**

If your layout will allow, you could include the sidebar a single time in index.html and render or not render it with ng-if based on a scope variable that you set by checking $routeParams.

In that case, your 'mainController' would look like this:

```
.controller('MainController', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {

     $scope.showSidebar = function(){
       if($routeParams.paramName == 'login'){
           return false;
       }else{
           return true;
       }
     };

 })
```

Then in index.html

```
<sidebar ng-if="showSidebar()"></sidebar>
```

Comment: I'm using UIRouter and with that aproach, I had to call <sidebar></sidebar> in every view. I think that's not the best(or the cleanest) way to it, right?

Comment: Well, if your layout can handle the width change, you could include <sidebar></sidebar> once in index.js and use ng-if to show/hide it based on a scope variable that you set using $routeParams ... I'll edit my answer with that option

Comment: That's what I got right now and it's working, but still don't know if it's the best solution. ;)

Answer (score 0):

So I guess you want to avoid having to include the sidebar in every view you make?

Maybe something like this?

In your route file, you can create an extra parameter like this:

```
$stateProvider
          .state('login', {
              url: '/login',
              templateUrl: '/App/tpl/login.html',
              hideSideBar: true
          })
```

Which you can then access in your controller/directive like this:

```
$state.current.hideSideBar;
```

That way you can include the sidebar in your main layout and hide it when set to true like this:

```
<div id="sidebar" data-ng-hide="controller.hideSideBar">
  .... your sidebar
</div>
```

(this is all written from memory so it may not work straight out of the box, but it should get you started)